# Apache automated installation

Tags: apache

Is it possible to install Apache with a script/batch file?

Comment: You might be better off asking this question at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sure is...

```
 apt-get install apache2
```

right inside the ol' batch file, depending on your package manager.

If you wanted to install from source, just

```
wget linktoapachesource.com
```

and put all the steps you would normally take inside a bash script.

Comment: Parameters of the Apache installation - where they should be stored?

Comment: store them in the same line in which you would enter them. Bash script will just execute the lines that you would normally enter by hand. So if you have specific flags when you are building, just include them in the line representing the command.\